# Why does the Cron user show as logged in to the site in Joomla Admin area?

Tags: cron

This is a new phenomenon since updating to latest CIVI.
Joomla 3.5.1
CIVI 4.7.3

Comment: Same here. Sites with versions not yet updated, no Cron user in the list. Where updates were done, Cron users shows one time to each run hour. Maybe something to do with:  PHP Warning:  Missing argument 1 for CRM_Utils_System_Joomla::getDefaultSiteSettings(), called in /adm.../CRM/Utils/System/Joomla.php on line 687 and defined in /adm.../CRM/Utils/System/Joomla.php on line 698 PHP Warning:  Missing argument 1 for CRM_Utils_System_Joomla::getDefaultSiteSettings(), called in /adm.../CRM/Utils/System/Joomla.php on line 687 and defined in /adm.../CRM/Utils/System/Joomla.php on line 698